# Disabling spring boot actuator not working in Spring boot 2.6.7

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-actuator

When I included the `spring-boot-starter-actuator` jar, whenever I hit the health endpoint (`/actuator/health`), I observed that Rabbit health indicator coming built-in from the jar was invoked. To disable this, I have included the following line in the application.properties file

```
management.health.rabbit.enabled=false
```

While this worked perfectly fine with spring-boot 2.5.7 jar, it is not working with spring-boot 2.6.7 jar (i.e. the Rabbit health indicator is running on this version even after disabling it in application.properties file). Not sure what needs to be done in the latter version. Can someone please help me here?

Comment: `management.health.rabbit.enabled` should work as before. I just tried to reproduce the behavior that you have described and could not do so. Can you provide a minimal example that shows the property having no effect?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, thanks for the quick response. I am suspecting that my application.properties file is not pushed properly to the environment. I will check this and confirm. Thanks